# ANTLR4 grammar no viable alternative at input

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, context-free-grammar, ambiguous-grammar

I am working on a project and I have to create a parser for the following grammar:

```
grammar T;
```

I am trying to read this piece of code:

```
theory oo
begin

builtins: asymmetric-encryption
functions: f/1  // f/1 used for function in protocol

/* Channel rules */ 

rule ChanOut_S:
    [Out_S($A,$B,xn,x)]
    --[ChanOut_S($A,$B,xn,x)]->
    [!Sec($A,$B,xn,x)]
```

I used to generate the parser tree using grun as follows:

grun T theory oo.spthy -gui

But every time I try to generate the parser tree I have the following error:

```
line 9:5 no viable alternative at input 'ruleC'
```

It seems the grammar has some problem but I am not able to figure it out.
Do you have any clue?

Comment: I don't see `ruleC` in the input you're parsing.

Comment: @BartKiers It's on the line `rule ChanOut_S:`.

Comment: The rule the parser should use is protoRule : 'rule' identifier  ':' genericRule but for some reason is not able to go there.

Comment: Ah, the space is not displayed by ANTLR's error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the lexer is getting confused by these two rules:

```
ALPHA : 'A'..'Z';

ALPH : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');
```

Since the first letter of `ChanOut_S` matches the rule ALPHA, the C gets consumed by that lexer rule. If you switch the order of those two rules, the entire identifier is recognized.

```
ALPH : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');

ALPHA : 'A'..'Z';
```

Comment: Yes, it is working!! Thanks! But know the parse is not able to read Out_S($A,$B,xn,x) giving this error: mismatched input 'O' expecting {'!', ALPHA}! Why?

Comment: @user1319267 It looks like `Out_S($A,$B,xn,x)` doesn't match any of the definitions for `fact`.

Comment: True! It was missing  factIdentifier '(' msetterm (',' msetterm)* ')'

Comment: Ok, I fixed the grammar but I still have the problem! in fact, I got the same error! If I see the parser tree, the parser sees there is a genericRule, sees the facts but at the first fact is not able to read Out_S($A,$B,xn,x) even if now there is the rule.

Comment: @user1319267 I'm not sure what's causing it, but I think it might be the `$`. I only see those as part of the `nonnode_var` definition, and I don't see that anywhere as a component of `msetterm`.